# Overwrite ID values using UPDATE statement from SELECT in another table SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have two tables that have exactly 20 rows in them. I want to overwrite Table2's ID values with the ID values from Table1 so that I can do tests with JOIN queries. How would I go about overwriting the values?

I have found posts instructing how to do an UPDATE using a SELECT statement, however it requires the data to be joined on a column, in my case no columns match.

```
UPDATE Table2
SET Table2.ID = Table1.ID
FROM Table1
```

The query above overwrites all ID columns in Table2 with the value of the first ID column in Table1.

Comment: Rows of tables should somehow correlates, only then you can join tables by related columns. Otherwise no chance to join tables. Is it for studying SQL or this is real application tables? In case of studying I would suggest to extend tables be few more columns liks  and rename tables, smth like: Cars and CarTypes. Cars: Id, TypeId, Name. CarTypes: Id, Name. So you can join Cars.TypeId ON CarTypes.Id

Comment: If this is a one-off for testing the easiest option for just 20 rows would be to open Table2 in SSMS and type the ID values in.

Comment: If you don't want to type them in manually, you'll have to create row numbers in query over both tables separately, and set ID = ID when Row + Row, and that's just more work than it's worth for 20 records.

Comment: If no columns match, how can you possibly know which ID from Table2 that a given row in Table1 should get? Does it matter? Can we "randomly" assign each row in Table1 any ID we wish from Table2 as long as the ID values in Table1 remain unique?

Comment: I'm aware it's possible to do this via the SSMS manually. I wanted to see if there was a query solution for doing transactions like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And another solution, this time using CTE's. Table `#First` gets the id's from table `#Second`:

```
CREATE TABLE #First ( ID INT NOT NULL )
INSERT INTO #First VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
CREATE TABLE #Second ( ID INT NOT NULL )
INSERT INTO #Second VALUES (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)
GO

WITH first AS (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum FROM #First)
   , second AS (SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum FROM #Second)
UPDATE #First
SET ID = s.ID
FROM second s
JOIN first f ON s.RowNum = f.RowNum
WHERE #First.ID = f.ID

SELECT * FROM #First

DROP TABLE #First;
DROP TABLE #Second;
```

Answer (score 4):

For fun (yes I have a warped sense of humour for a Friday night!), here is a query that does it! - I've declare the tables and the top and only used 6 rows in each table, but you'll get the idea:

```
--Setup test data
declare @table1 table (ID int, Name varchar(10))
declare @table2 table (ID int, Name varchar(10))

insert @table1
    select ID = 1, Name = 'Item1'
    union select ID = 2, Name = 'Item2'
    union select ID = 3, Name = 'Item3'
    union select ID = 4, Name = 'Item4'
    union select ID = 5, Name = 'Item5'
    union select ID = 6, Name = 'Item6'

insert @table2
    select ID = 11, Name = 'Item11'
    union select ID = 12, Name = 'Item12'
    union select ID = 13, Name = 'Item13'
    union select ID = 14, Name = 'Item14'
    union select ID = 15, Name = 'Item15'
    union select ID = 16, Name = 'Item16'


--Do the update
update t1
    set 
        ID = t2.ID
from
    @table1 t1 --Assign a row number to each row of table 1
    cross apply (select rownum = COUNT(1) from @table1 sub where sub.ID <= t1.ID) x1,
    @table2 t2 --Assign a row number to each row of table 2
    cross apply (select rownum = COUNT(1) from @table2 sub where sub.ID <= t2.ID) x2
where x1.rownum = x2.rownum --Match the row numbers
```

---

Update:

Alternative Update command based on suggestion by @sllev:

```
update t1
    set 
        ID = t2.ID
from
    (select id, rownum  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by ID) from @table1) t1
    join (select id, rownum  = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) from @table2) t2
        on t1.rownum = t2.rownum
```

Comment: Why not to use ROW_NUMBER OVER() to generate sequence manually?

Comment: I find that as messy when working it into the from clause, I'll have a look though and update if it doesn't work out too bad

Comment: @sllev +1 for `ROW_NUMBER OVER()` I had not used it before. @Jon Egerton +1 for the examples and showing me different ways of playing with the data. @Ronald Wildenberg's answer worked best for me but I appreciate the information.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have 20 rows in them, I would manually perform the update by typing in your changes. Especially since the records do not correlate to each other as they typically should for an update with a select.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, if this is a one-off for testing the easiest option for just 20 rows would be to open Table2 in SSMS and type the ID values in.